# FlutterDriver - how to close showDialog

Tags: flutter, dismiss, showdialog, flutterdriver

I am working with FlutterDriver, I have an IconButton defined and a key set as shown:

```
Center(
  child: IconButton(
    key: Key('moredots'),
    icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
    onPressed: () {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) => tableConfig,        
      );
    },
  ),
)
```

The dialog is successfully shown with the following code:

```
await driver.tap(find.byValueKey('moredots'));
```

What I can't figure out is how to dismiss the dialog. I've tried:

- Tapping the same value as shown above
- Adding a key in Scaffold, finding the key and tapping
- Adding keys in other UI elements in the hierarchy, finding and tapping

The error message I receive is:

> FlutterDriver: tap message is taking a long time to complete...

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that showDialog() presents a ModalBarrier to stop user input while the dialog is shown.

The trick to close the showDialog is to find by type passing in the ModalBarrier as shown here:

```
await driver.tap(find.byType(ModalBarrier));
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me with Flutter 1.17.5. Which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
```

after

`await driver.tap(find.byValueKey('moredots')`);

Comment: what does `.pop(false)` do?

Comment: You don't need the false, but its the return value when dialogue is closed.

Comment: Thanks for the input, however, this answer will not work, integration tests with FlutterDriver cannot have Flutter UI code.